# Indy-node installation fails on Ubuntu

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I'm trying to install indy-node on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 machine in order to create a small network with 4 nodes.

when following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/start-nodes.md) I get the following error:

```
localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install indy-node

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indy-node : Depends: indy-plenum (= 1.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libsodium18 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried installing `libsodium18` but I get the following error:

```
Package libsodium18 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libsodium18' has no installation candidate
```

Likewise, trying to install `indy-plenum` has a bunch of 'unmet dependency' errors.

**Note:* this is all happens with the following repo:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial stable" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

when I try to add the packages for bionic instead of xenial, I get the following error:

```
repository 'https://repo.sovrin.org/deb bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable'
```

I have also tried to install indy-node via python + pip, but that doesn't seem to work either.

**Has anyone successfully installed indy-node, and if so, can you share the secret?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've generated Docker images for Indy-Node using Ubuntu 18.04, but had to build libsodium from source. You can see the source dockerfile here although there are git URLs that get replaced by the build script: https://github.com/PSPC-SPAC-buyandsell/von-image/blob/master/node-1.9/Dockerfile.ubuntu

The final images are at https://hub.docker.com/r/bcgovimages/von-image/tags (the node-* images, latest is `bcgovimages/von-image:node-1.12-2`)

I believe the Indy-Node team are shortly going to be updating to 20.04 for the image used in testing.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll checkout those images out.

Comment: I know that this comment is old, but I assume that the images from VON network are not intended for production use, right?

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the end was to downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04